# TCP server/client how to keep connections alive?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I wrote a simple TCP echo server to handle multiple clients. It uses select() to get multiple connections.

Server Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>


int create_listener(uint16_t port) {

    int listen_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in name;

    listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listen_fd < 0) {
        perror ("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    bzero(&name, sizeof(name));
    name.sin_family = AF_INET;
    name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    name.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(name)) < 0) {
        perror ("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    return listen_fd;
}

int read_from_client(int fd) {
    char buffer[100];
    int nbytes;

    nbytes = read(fd, buffer, 100);
    if (nbytes < 0) {
        perror("read");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (nbytes == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Server: got message: %s\n", buffer);
        write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);
        return 0;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int listen_fd;
    uint16_t port = 22000;

    fd_set active_fd_set, read_fd_set;
    int i;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    /* Create the socket and set it up to accept connections. */
    listen_fd = create_listener(port);
    if (listen(listen_fd, 10) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Initialize the set of active sockets. */
    FD_ZERO(&active_fd_set);
    FD_SET(listen_fd, &active_fd_set);


    while (1) {

        /* Block until input arrives on one or more active sockets. */
        read_fd_set = active_fd_set;
        if (select(FD_SETSIZE, &read_fd_set, NULL, NULL, 0) < 0) {
            perror("select");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* Service all the sockets with input pending. */
        for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; ++i) {
            if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fd_set)) {
                if (i == listen_fd) {
                    /* Connection request on original socket. */
                    int new_fd;
                    new_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);

                    if (new_fd < 0) {
                        perror ("accept");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                    FD_SET(new_fd, &active_fd_set);
                }
                else {
                    /* Data arriving on an already-connected socket. */
                    if (read_from_client(i) < 0) {
                        close(i);
                        FD_CLR(i, &active_fd_set);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int sockfd, n;
    char sendline[100];
    char recvline[100];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(22000);

    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(servaddr.sin_addr));

    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));


    while (1) {
        bzero(sendline, 100);
        bzero(recvline, 100);
        fgets(sendline, 100, stdin);

        write(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline) + 1);
        read(sockfd, recvline, 100);

        printf("%s", recvline);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I run server in one terminal and run two clients in another two terminals. If I use Ctrl+C to terminate one client, the server automatically terminates. I'm wondering why the server acts this way. What I'm expecting is the server runs forever. When client 1 terminates, server should still has a live connection with client 2.

Comment: Could you be hitting the `exit` in `read_from_client`?

Comment: @Andy Schweig You got it. Please answer it and I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're hitting the `exit` in `read_from_client`. In general, in a server that serves multiple clients, you probably don't want to exit when you have a failure with one of the client connections.